# Android - Navigate back to app from System Settings

Tags: android, navigation, settings, system, back

On my login activity, I check if the user has activated/ turned on their GPS.
If not, I simply display an `AlertDialog` asking the user to switch on the GPS.

From the `AlertDialog` I launch/start an Intent as follows:

```
Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
startActivity(settingsIntent);
```

When pressing the back button from the System Settings the user returns to the phone's home screen...  i.e "closing the app".

I have tried `onActivityResult` but to no avail.
Furthermore, I have read up on similar problems other users had but it proofed
pointless as most answers related back to using `onActivityResult`.

Can someone please shine some light on the matter?

**Edit:**
Here is the full code for the `AlertDialog`:

```
builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("GPS Not Found");
builder.setMessage("Want To Enable?");

//Dialog - Yes option
builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
{
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i)
{
Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
startActivityForResult(settingsIntent,1);
}
});

//Dialog - No option                
builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
{
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i)
{

}
});

//Show he dialog
builder.create().show();
```

**Edit:**
Here are the `OnPause()` and `OnResume()` methods.  I simply check to see if the provider is still active and the same with the `locationManager`.
Neither "TEST 1" nor "TEST 2" gets printed when I go back from Settings.

```
@Override
protected void onResume()
{
  Log.i(ERRORTAG, "TEST 1");

  super.onResume();
  if(provider != null)
  {
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, refreshTime, refreshDistance, this);
    gpsEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
  }
}


@Override
protected void onPause()
{
  Log.i(ERRORTAG, "TEST 2");


  super.onPause();
  if(locationManager != null)
  {
    locationManager.removeUpdates((LocationListener) this);
    gpsEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
  }


  if(loginDialog != null)
  {
    loginDialog.dismiss();
  }
}
```

Comment: can you show the whole code to your `AlertDialog`?  I suspect you are calling `finish()` in there somewhere.

Comment: The behavior of the Settings app may vary by device manufacturer, as they tend to tinker with this app more than others. While it should normally return to you (AFAIK), that is not required. Though as iagreen points out, there may be something in the way that you are starting the activity that will cause above-average difficulties in this area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted out the problem.
In the manifest file, the activity had the tag `noHistory="true"` which (to my understanding) doesn't add it to the stack.
Hence can't go "back" to the activity.

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling `finish();` somewhere after your `startActivity()` or in `onPause()`?
Looking at the [Activity Life Cycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) you see that `onPause()` is called when your start the Settings-Intent.

Comment: I included my `onPause()` and `onResume()` methods in the edit.

Comment: The code looks okay. Run you app on an emulator to make sure it is not a device specific problem.